# Wondering how to get my ENV variables into supervisor

Tags: environment-variables, supervisord

In my ~/.bashrc I set the below variables...they work fine in my python script when I launch it but when I use supervisor it can't fine

**FAILURE**

```
[supervisor]

environment=ORACLE_HOME="%(ORACLE_HOME)s",LD_LIBRARY_PATH="%(LD_LIBRARY_PATH)s"
```

**SUCCESS**

```
[supervisor]

environment=ORACLE_HOME="/path/to/it",LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/it"
```

Basically I don't want to go back into the config file every time I want to update the oracle instant client.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this executing these commands and then start supervisor

```
>> sudo export ORACLE_HOME="/path/to/it"
>> sudo export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/it"
>> . ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to add `ENV_` prefix in getting the env value

```
environment=ORACLE_HOME=%(ENV_ORACLE_HOME)s,LD_LIBRARY_PATH=%(ENV_LD_LIBRARY_PATH)s
```

or run you command by using `bash`. In this case all env variables will be available

```
command=/bin/bash -c 'your command here'
```